# Passing Json Data To Another ViewController Table On Button Click

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, storyboard, cell

I am developing an ios app..On Button Click Json Data To Pass Another ViewController...But TableView Not Show Json Data..TableView Show Empty

```
 BBAdsViewController *BBAuthorDetail =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AdsViewController"];

        [BBAuthorDetail setDelegate:self];
        [BBAuthorDetail setSelectionType:BBSelectionAuthorName];
        _serverObj = [[Server alloc]init];
        [_params setObject:_adDetailsObj.authorDetail forKey:@"author"];
        [_serverObj BBAuthorNameWithParams:_params];
     [BBAuthorDetail setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:BBAuthorDetail animated:YES];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell-%li", (long)indexPath.row];
    BBAdsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    Ad *adObj = (Ad *)[self.adsFilteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BBAdsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.row = indexPath.row;
        [cell setDelegate:self];
    }

    if (![adObj.gallery isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adObj.gallery]];
        [cell.adImageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ship_placeholder.png"] success:nil failure:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.adImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ship_placeholder.png"]];
    }
    if (_serverCallType == ServerCallTypeAdvancedSearch || _serverCallType == ServerCallTypeSearch ) {
        [cell.phoneButton setHidden:NO];
        [cell.categoryLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.authorLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.addressLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.favButton setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(cell.phoneButton.frame) + 25.0f, CGRectGetMidY(cell.phoneButton.frame))];
    }    else
    {
        [cell.phoneButton setHidden:YES];
        [cell.favButton setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame) - 30.0f, 65.0f)];
    }

    if (_selectionType == BBSelectionBoat || _selectionType == BBSelectionOtherBoat || _selectionType == BBlatestBoat )
    {
        if (adObj.price && ![adObj.price isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [cell.priceLabel setHidden:NO];
            [cell.priceLabel setText:adObj.price];
        }
        [cell.categoryLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.authorLabel.frame), CGRectGetMinY(cell.authorLabel.frame) - 7.0f)];

        if (_serverCallType == ServerCallTypeAdvancedSearch || _serverCallType == ServerCallTypeSearch)
        {
            [cell.authorLabel setHidden:YES];
            [cell.addressLabel setHidden:YES];

        }

        else
        {
            cell.authorLabel.text = adObj.authorName;
            cell.addressLabel.text = adObj.address;
            [cell.authorLabel setHidden:YES];
            [cell.addressLabel setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.priceLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.authorLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.addressLabel setHidden:YES];

        [cell.categoryLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.addressLabel.frame), CGRectGetMidY(cell.addressLabel.frame))];
    }

    [cell.favButton setSelected:adObj.isFavorite];
    NSRange range = [adObj.title rangeOfString:@","];
    cell.titleLabel.text = range.location == NSNotFound ? adObj.title : [adObj.title substringToIndex:range.location];
    [cell.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    cell.categoryLabel.text = adObj.category;
    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't explain much. It seems you are calling a web service to get the data. And using core data in your application. Please explain it in a detail so that it could be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Below are simple example for pass a data from one view controler to another.

```
//FirstViewController.m

//on button click

SecondViewController *secondViewContrler = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];


secondViewContrler.dataArray = dataArrayWithData; //assign value



//SecondViewController.h

@property (retain , nonatomic) NSMutableArray* dataArray;

//SecondViewController.m
@synthesize dataArray;
```